# keep modal title at top when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a modal, html:

```
 <div class="modal__container">
    <div class="modal__container-title">
      Title
      <div class="text-lg" @click="closeModal">&times;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal__container-content">
      <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
.modal__container {
width: 95%;
max-width: 780px;
max-height: 680px;
overflow-y: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
.modal__container-title {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.modal__container-content {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
}
}
```

I'm trying to move the scroll bar into modal content, so that I can keep the modal title at top when scrolling, but can not find a way to do so. I've tried to move overflow-y: auto; into .modal__container-content but it failed. Please help, thank you.

Example is here: https://codepen.io/uu9924079/pen/PoPoZNv?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is to add the following to `.modal__container-title`:

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

This will not move the scrollbar into the content though, it will just fix the heading to the top of the scrollable area.